# Is it possible to use Selenium to interact with a webpage accessed with requests?

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

I'm using requests to access a webpage.

```
header = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'
    }

page = requests.get("https://example.com/",header)
```

I would like to use Selenium to click on an element without reconnecting to the page using Selenium.

I imagined something like although I know it wouldn't be that simple:

```
page.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/p[2]/a").click()
```

Thanks in advance if it's possible !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

Selenium **drives web browsers** which means a web browser needs to download the full page (which will include images, css, scripts, etc.), build to DOM, execute javascript, to build a representation of the page similar to how a user might see it. Then, Selenium queries the browser to retrieve info for you.

python requests simply downloads a single file, not the full web page. And requests doesn't execute embedded javascript, or build the DOM.

(You can use BeautifulSoup to parse the python-requests returned HTML, and that might help you, but the result is more like reading XML files, than clicking on web pages.)